# How to process multiple parquet files individually in a for loop?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have multiple parquet files (around 1000). I need to load each one of them, process it and save the result to a Hive table. I have a for loop but it only seems to work with 2 or 5 files, but not with 1000, as it seems Sparks tries to load them all at the same time, and I need it do it individually in the same Spark session.

I tried using a for loop, then a for each, and I ussed unpersist() but It fails anyway.

```
val ids = get_files_IDs()
ids.foreach(id => {
println("Starting file " + id)
var df = load_file(id)
var values_df = calculate_values(df)
values_df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("table.values_" + id)
df.unpersist()
})

def get_files_IDs(): List[String] = {
var ids = sqlContext.sql("SELECT CAST(id AS varchar(10)) FROM  table.ids WHERE id IS NOT NULL")
var ids_list = ids.select("id").map(r => r.getString(0)).collect().toList
return ids_list
}

def calculate_values(df:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame ={
val values_id = df.groupBy($"id", $"date", $"hr_time").agg(avg($"value_a") as "avg_val_a", avg($"value_b") as "avg_value_b")
return values_id
}

def load_file(id:String): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = {
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/user/hive/wh/table.db/parquet/values_for_" + id + ".parquet")
return df
}
```

What I would expect is for Spark to load file ID 1, process the data, save it to the Hive table and then dismiss that date and cotinue with the second ID and so on until it finishes the 1000 files. Instead of it trying to load everything at the same time.

Any help would be very appreciated! I've been stuck on it for days. I'm using Spark 1.6 with Scala Thank you!!

EDIT: Added the definitions. Hope it can help to get a better view. Thank you!

Comment: whats the type of `ids`?

Comment: Why do you use `var` unstead of `val`? Try to unpersist `values_df` as well. I don't know what logic you have in you `load_file` and `calculate_values` but you can also try to do `sparkSession.sqlContext.clearCache()` after unpersisting your dataframes.

Comment: show us `load_file`

Comment: Hello, thank your reposnes. I have added the definitions, that the whole code I'm using. I will test what @DmitryY. suggest. I'm using var just to see if it made a difference, I was using val since the begginign. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of inspection I realised that the process was working fine. It processed each file individualy and saved the results. The issue was that in some very specific cases the process was taking way way way to long.

So I can tell that with a for loop or for each you can process multiple files and save the results without problem. Unpersisting and clearing cache do helps on performance.